# How to fix the code about appending a number in the line?

Tags: python-3.x, csv, append

I create a new column (name:Account) in the csv, then try to make a sequence (c = float(a) + float(b)) and for each number in sequence append to the original line in the csv, which is the value of the new column. Here is my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import csv
with open('./tradedate/2007date.csv') as inf:
reader = csv.reader(inf)
all = []
row = next(reader)
row.append('Amount')
all.append(row)

a =50 
for i, line in enumerate(inf):
    if i != 0:
        size = sum(1 for _ in inf) # count the line number

        for b in range(1, size+1): 
            c = float(a) + float(b) # create the sequence: in 1st line add 1, 2nd line add 2, 3rd line add 3...etc

            line.append(c) # this is the error message: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'
            all.append(line)

with open('main_test.csv', 'w', newline = '') as new_csv:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(new_csv)
    csv_writer.writerows(all)
```

The csv is like this:

```
日期,成交股數,成交金額,成交筆數,發行量加權股價指數,漲跌點數,Account
96/01/02,"5,738,692,838","141,743,085,172","1,093,711","7,920.80",97.08,51
96/01/03,"5,974,259,385","160,945,755,016","1,160,347","7,917.30",-3.50,52
96/01/04,"5,747,756,529","158,857,947,106","1,131,747","7,934.51",17.21,53
96/01/05,"5,202,769,867","143,781,214,318","1,046,480","7,835.57",-98.94,54
96/01/08,"4,314,344,739","115,425,522,734","888,324","7,736.71",-98.86,55
96/01/09,"4,533,381,664","120,582,511,893","905,970","7,790.01",53.30,56
```

The Error message is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 21, in <module>
line.append(c)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Very thanks for any help!!

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you want to achieve. Can you post the desired output csv file? The error occurs because you iterate over the lines (strings) and try to `.append` something to them,  but strings don't have an `append` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little confused why you're structuring your code this way, but the simplest fix would be to change the append (since you can't append to a string) to += a string version of c, i.e.

```
line += str(c)
```

or

```
line += ',{}'.format(c)
```

(I'm not clear based on how you're written this if you need the comma or not)

The biggest problem is that you're not using your csv reader - below is a better implementation.  With the csv reader it's cleaner to do the append that you want to do versus using the file object directly.

```
import csv

with open('./tradedate/2007date.csv') as old_csv:
    with open('main_test.csv', 'w') as new_csv:
        writer = csv.writer(new_csv, lineterminator='\n')
        reader = csv.reader(old_csv)

        all = []
        row = next(reader)
        row.append('Line Number')
        all.append(row)

        line_number = 51
        for row in reader:
            row.append(line_number)
            all.append(row)
            line_number += 1

        writer.writerows(all)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I think there are some basic concept that I am not so clear as a beginner of Python and programming language! Right now I understand, thanks again!!